# Can we call a function from another function created in a class in Python? If yes then how to do it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I actually got a error while performing this type of operation

```
class atm:
    def fun1(self):
        print("func1 has been called")
    def fun2(self):
        print("func2 has been called")
        fun1()
q=atm()
q.fun2()
```

Comment: It's `self.fun1()`.

Comment: is there a reason you didn't include any information about the error you get?